# Showing multiple .fig files in one plot

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a relatively simple function which allows me to plot any numbers of figures (previously saved as .fig files) one close to the other.

I have looked for the solution in the website, but it does not work for me.
Moreover, I am almost there with my code, since the outputs are almost what I want: indeed I get the two figures in the right position, but in two separate windows and a third window which is correctly merging the two inputs, but they look weird, with a lower resolution! So I get three outputs in total.

Here is my code, I hope you can help me.
(Try with your own .fig files and check if you also have the three wrong outputs like me).

```
function SubPlotFig (varargin)

for i = 1:nargin
hf = hgload(varargin{i});
ax(i) = findobj(hf,'Type','axes');
end

hc = figure;
for i = 1:nargin
subplot(1,2,i,ax(i)); 
copyobj(ax(i),hc); 
end
```

[Attachment_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXnyP.jpg)
[Attachment_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6poYE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the colormap. Now it is solved. Here is the correct code, can be useful for others :)

```
function SubPlotFig (varargin)

for i = 1:nargin
hf = openfig(varargin{i},'reuse');
cm = colormap;
c(i) = findobj(hf,'Type','Colorbar');
ax(i) = findobj(hf,'Type','Axes');
end

hc = figure;
for i = 1:nargin
subplot(1,2,i,ax(i));
copyobj(ax(i),hc); 
colormap(ax(i),cm);
copyobj([c(i),ax(i)],hc);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `hgload`, it will open a figure from a .fig file *and display it*. You are doing this inside of your first loop, so you will see a figure for each of the inputs. The figure that you see is *exactly* what you saved for each figure.

```
for i = 1:nargin
    hf = hgload(varargin{i});           % <---- Creates a figure
    ax(i) = findobj(hf,'Type','axes');
end
```

In the second loop, you create a `subplot` for each of the `axes` within the figures that you just opened. These of course are going to be smaller because you are now putting multiple `axes` within a `figure` that is the default size. They aren't really "low resolution", just smaller on the screen. If you want to make them bigger, then you'll want to increase your figure size.

```
% Create all of the subplots
hc = figure;
for i = 1:nargin
    hax = subplot(1,2,i,ax(i)); 
    copyobj(ax(i),hc); 
    colorbar(hax);
end

% Make sure we are using the jet colormap
colormap(jet)

% Get the current figure position
pos = get(hc, 'Position');

% Double the width since you now have two plots
set(hc, 'Position', [pos(1:2) pos(3)*2, pos(4)])
```

Comment: Thank you Suever! The problem unfortunately persists: the figures are now bigger, but still different from the original ones! I have added two attachments to clarify it :)

Comment: @Angy So what are the differences you care about? The colormap? The aspect ratio of the plot? The lack of colorbars? You're never going to be able to produce them *exactly* this way. If you want them to appear identical, you're better off saving each figure as an image and then combining those in another program.

Comment: I think the problem is the colorbar, copyobj does not copy it to the new figure. In Attachment_1 the result is exactly like the original one (good!), but the there is only one figure, the other one is missing. In Attachment_2 you have both of them (good!), but they look different from the original ones (colormap?)

Comment: @Angy You can change the colormap and colorbar. Read my answer again and you'll see why figure 1 looks exactly like the origina. I'll add some code to switch your colormaps and colorbar

Comment: I just solved it! I will edit the original post. Thank you Suever!